# Centering from array package won't work

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, arrays

I'm working on a table right now and I would really like to center it to make it look neater.  Only problem is after I import the array package, and then use the m{width} function. It doesn't seem to do anything. Any idea why?  Here's the code and picture of the table.
Also, there's these error markers and are all saying the same thing as the one highlighted in the code below.  What do these mean, I've been trying to figure that out but cant seem to find a solution.

```
\begin{table}[htpb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{m{2.5cm}|m{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Reduced data}} \\ \cline{1-2}
{} & Average Mass [kg]$\pm$0.0001 & Average Radius [m]$\pm$0.00001 & Experimental Height [m]$\pm$0.00305 & Theoretical Height [m]\\
\hline
Ball Type    &                          &                             &                                 & \\ \hline
Table Tennis &                  0.00248 &                     0.01871 &                         0.24831 &   0.34973 $\pm$0.00519 \\
Racquet      &                  0.04172 &                     0.02803 &                         0.51206 &   0.70837 $\pm$0.00787 \\
Squash       &                  0.02382 &                     0.01978 &                         0.09103 &   0.12059 $\pm$0.01629 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

-Thanks

Comment: Does switching *all* the `p` columns to `m` columns do what you want?

Comment: `m` does not centre the content in the space of the cell, it aligns the vertical centre of the content with the baseline of the row, so it doesn't do anything useful for a one line entry. and aligns the centre of the 2-line heading of column 2 with the first line of the p columns, which again is not wanted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sligthly modified AboAmmar answer ... by help of `makecell` package for setting column heads in two lines you can obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

    \usepackage{booktabs,makecell}

    \begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}}
    \toprule
    &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Reduced data}}                       \\
    \cmidrule{2-5}
    &   \thead{Average Mass\\ {[kg]$\pm$0.0001}} 
        &   \thead{Average Radius\\ {[m]$\pm$0.00001}}
            &   \thead{Experimental Height\\ {[m]$\pm$0.00305}}
                &   \thead{Theoretical Height\\ {[m]}}\\
\hline
Ball Type    &          &           &           &                        \\ 
    \midrule
Table Tennis &  0.00248 &   0.01871 &   0.24831 &   0.34973 $\pm$0.00519 \\
Racquet      &  0.04172 &   0.02803 &   0.51206 &   0.70837 $\pm$0.00787 \\
Squash       &  0.02382 &   0.01978 &   0.09103 &   0.12059 $\pm$0.01629 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

If ypu like to have column heads in the same font size as whole table, than you need to add in preamble (after loading `makecell` package):

```
 \renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
```

**Edit:**
And version, if you like to have column headers in three lines and merged 2nd and 3th table row:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{booktabs,makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}

    \begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}}
    \toprule
    &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Reduced data}}                       \\
    \cmidrule{2-5}
\thead{~\\~\\ \textbf{Ball Type}}
    &   \thead{Average\\ Mass\\ {[kg]$\pm$0.0001}} 
        &   \thead{Average\\ Radius\\ {[m]$\pm$0.00001}}
            &   \thead{Experimental\\ Height\\ {[m]$\pm$0.00305}}
                &   \thead{Theoretical\\ Height\\ {[m]}}\\
    \midrule
Table Tennis &  0.00248 &   0.01871 &   0.24831 &   0.34973 $\pm$0.00519 \\
Racquet      &  0.04172 &   0.02803 &   0.51206 &   0.70837 $\pm$0.00787 \\
Squash       &  0.02382 &   0.01978 &   0.09103 &   0.12059 $\pm$0.01629 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htpb]
\centering\small
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}c}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Reduced data}} \\ \cmidrule{2-5}
& Average    & Average   & Experimental & Theoretical \\
& Mass [kg]  & Radius [m]& Height [m]           & Height [m]  \\
\textbf{Ball Type} & $\pm$0.0001 & $\pm$0.00001 & $\pm$0.00305 &  \\ \midrule
Table Tennis &  0.00248  &  0.01871 &   0.24831 &   0.34973 $\pm$0.00519 \\
Racquet      &  0.04172  &  0.02803 &   0.51206 &   0.70837 $\pm$0.00787 \\
Squash       &  0.02382  &  0.01978 &   0.09103 &   0.12059 $\pm$0.01629 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Thank you, that was `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l*{4}C}` with custom `newcolumntype{C}` defined as centered `X`at first, and at a last-moment edit, I just removed the capital C leaving out other parts.

Answer (score 0):

currently add a new columntyp to your code.

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % zentriert mit Breitenangabe
```

Otherwise provide a MWE.

Comment: This dos not address the question, which is about vertical centering and the use of `m`.