# How to improve this table formatted using tabular and array in terms of centering in the page and wrapping long words in first column?

Tags: tables, arrays, center

I am very much new to LaTeX and am unfamiliar with a lot of terms and usage. Nonetheless, I am attempting to put this table into a document. I am having two problems:

1. The table is not centred in the page (it spills into the right margin)
2. Long words (e.g. phenanthroline in column 1) are not auto-hyphenating

I am using the array package as I have seen it suggested for setting the column widths to auto wrap text, which seems to have been successful so far. I am also using booktabs just for the top, mid and bottom ruled lines.

I have come across [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271116/centering-from-array-package-wont-work) answer which seems similar to my problem and produces a result that looks good, but I can't quite understand how it works / what is being done with makecell package.

Any clarification or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
...
\begin{document}
...
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.8}
    \caption{Peak wavelength and absorbance measurements, calculated \(\Delta_O\) and \(\epsilon\) values}
    \label{tab:results-5.2}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{>{\raggedright}p{0.135\linewidth}>{\raggedright}p{0.125\linewidth}>{\raggedright}p{0.125\linewidth}>{\raggedright}p{0.115\linewidth}>{\raggedright}p{0.115\linewidth}>{\raggedright}p{0.135\linewidth}>{\raggedright}p{0.125\linewidth}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.125\linewidth}}
        \toprule
         Ligand & [complex] \([M]\) & Colour & \(\lambda_{max,1}\) \([nm]\) & \(\lambda_{max,2}\) \([nm]\) & Absorbance & \(\Delta_O\) \([eV]\) & \(\epsilon\) \([M^{-1} cm^{-1}]\) \\
         \midrule
         \ce{H2O} (II)              & nnnnnnnnn     & short text                                &nnnnn  &nnnnn  &nnnnn  &nnnn   &nnnn \\
         \ce{glycine}               & nnnnnnnnn     & short text                                &nnnnn  &nnnnn  &nnnnn  &nnnn   &nnnnn \\
         \ce{C_2O_4^{2-}}           & nnnnnnnnn     & short text                                &nnnnn  &nnnnn  &nnnnn  &nnnn   &nnnnn \\
         \ce{CO_3^{2-}}             & nnnnnnnnn     & long long long long long long long text   &nnnnn  &nnnnn  &nnnnn  &nnnn   &nnnn \\
         \ce{H_2O} (III)            & nnnnnnnnn     & short                                     &nnnnn  &nnnnn  &nnnnn  &nnnn   &nnn \\
         \ce{1,10-phen\-anthroline} & nnnnnnnnn     & short                                     &nnnnn  &nnnnn  &nnnnnn &nnnn   &nnn \\
         \ce{NO2^{-}}               & nnnnnnnnn     & long long long long text                  &nnnnn  &nnnnn  &nnnnn  &nnnn   &nnnn \\
         \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
...
\end{document}
```

[image: output table from code above overflowing text block with no line breaks]

Comment: Sequences of a single consonant are not words and in most languages hard to hyphenate. So `nnnnnnnnn` usually will not be hyphenated. PDFLaTeX and XeLaTeX do not hyphenate the first word of a paragraph, box or table column. You can add `\hskip 0pt` after the `\raggedright` to change this. But `\raggedright` does only hyphenate if a single word is wider than the available width. Maybe you want `\RaggedRight` of package `ragged2e`. When choosing the widths of the table columns, the column spacing was not taken into account. So the table is several `\tabcolsep` to wide.

Comment: Maybe useful to improve the table: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/277964)

Comment: Welcome! You might also find `tabularx` and/or the `rotating` packages useful. The former will calculate widths of columns for you and the latter can be used to turn a table sideways.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I have had some success using `tabularx` and just setting the width to be `1.2\textwidth` for example. I am only struggling now to get this table centred, any ideas?